# Laravel ManytoMany: How to attach a product to a user upon user registration?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, pivot-table

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create an application for our customers to confirm ownership of their products.
I created the following tables and models:

users table

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

products table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('etc');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

user_product table

```
Schema::create('user_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->index();
$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->timestamps();

});
```

user model

```
public function products()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'user_product')->withTimestamps();
 }
```

product model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

So here’s where I’m stuck…
I want to have a product displayed together with the user registration form.  Upon registration, the user has to confirm ownership of the product. So I need to associate the product displayed with the user account that is about to be created. Not sure how to do that though…

I am using ManyToMany because I want to have all the products in the database, even if they belong to a user or not. After the association between the user and the product, you cannot access that product without being logged in. 
I hope it makes a bit of sense, still working on the logistics behind this :)

Any idea of how to reach this scenario?
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If the product can only belong to a single user and a user can have many products you should use One To Many, and create a foreing key in the product table by calling user and would use the create () or save () function.
Using softdelete in the User model you do not risk deleting the user and their products.

But if you want a Many to Many relationship anyway use the attach () function as follows:

```
$user->produtcs()->attach($productId);
```

or else

```
$product->users()->attach($userId)
```

But both models already have to be in the database, both User and Product.

If you want to know which User owns the product you can add a user_owner_id field in the user_product table and add it in the attach like this:

```
$user->produtcs()->attach($productId, ['user_owner_id' => $userId]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I would have used the one-to-many but I want to have product without users, so that wasn't a good option. As for what you said about "But both models already have to be in the database, both User and Product." is this the only possible scenario? I wouldn't want to have users registered before they get "attached" to a product. I want to attach the product the moment a user account is created. Is this scenario possible at all?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can create the user at runtime
`$user = User::create($data)`
And then use no attach the created id. But ALWAYS have to use id in attach()
`$product->users()->attach($user->id)`